# Problems copying db file to iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I have a sqlite file that I need to be read by my iOS app, but xcode gives me an error copying it in the app...
I put the sql file in "Supporting files" folder of my project.
Here's the code:

```
-(NSString *)filePath {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                         NSUserDomainMask,
                                                         YES);

    return [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                                                         @"LocationsApp.sql"];
}

-(void)createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded {
    BOOL success;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSString *writableDBPath = [self filePath];
    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath];

    if (success)
    {
        return;
    }

    NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"LocationsApp.sql"];
    success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:writableDBPath error:&error];
    if (!success)
    {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```

and here's the error:

> 2013-10-03 13:21:35.282 LaGuida[1872:60b] *** Assertion failure in -[FirstViewController createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded], /Volumes/Lavoro/AppleDev/LaGuida/LaGuida/FirstViewController.m:87
>   2013-10-03 13:21:35.284 LaGuida[1872:60b]**  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Failed to create writable database file with message 'The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 260.)'.'
>   ** First throw call stack:
>   (0x2e4f8e8b 0x387f36c7 0x2e4f8d5d 0x2eea123f 0x6b201 0x6abad 0x30c8297d 0x30c828f9 0x30daa7cf 0x30daa663 0x30daa56f 0x30c8fed5 0x30dadeb5 0x30dad333 0x30c98907 0x30c8a5a7 0x30c89d5f 0x30c89bd3 0x30c89701 0x30c86cc5 0x30cf219d 0x30ceef75 0x30ce94b9 0x30c83be7 0x30c82edd 0x30ce8ca1 0x3316476d 0x33164357 0x2e4c377f 0x2e4c371b 0x2e4c1ee7 0x2e42c541 0x2e42c323 0x30ce7f43 0x30ce31e5 0x6bbdd 0x38cecab7)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Cocoa error 260: No such file, It looks like the file you are trying to copy from the bundle does not exists. Try and log the `defaultDBPath` and `writableDBPath`

Comment: Solved...wrong extension, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Correct your DBName**

```
LocationsApp.sql to LocationsApp.sqlite
```

or whatever your DBName is

Comment: I'm so stupid, wrong ext...filename was LocationsApp.db You gave me an important clue, Thanks ;)

Comment: @iMove you can name the file whatever you want, SQLite will still load it. there is nowhere is it specified that a SQLite file must have the extension `.sqlite`

Comment: @rckoenes i just go through this particular question in which giving error which is "No such file" that's why i just give him an idea

Comment: @Michele you are always welcome dude you solve your problam i m happy..:)

Comment: @iMove I know that I can give my db filename any kind of extension, but the problem was that I wrote a .sql extension rather than .db (the one that my file has)